# TypeScript: conditional return type OK on usage, but not in the return statement

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to write a TS function returning a conditional type.
Basically, if the function receives an object with an "email" property, it returns it, otherwise it returns nothing:

```js
type WithEmail = { email: string, [k: string]: unknown };

function getEmail<T extends Partial<WithEmail>>(obj: T)
: T extends WithEmail ? T['email'] : void {
    if (obj.email) {
        return obj.email;
    }

    return;
}

// email1 is indeed a "string"
const email1 = getEmail({ email: 'foo@bar.com' });

// email2 is indeed a "void"
const email2 = getEmail({ name: 'Foo' });
```

➡️ [Link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgUQLYEM4BsoF4oDeUEG2AXFAM7ABOcAdgOYA0UA2gNYXV1MC6FAK70O9APYB3elAC+AbgBQCgGbCAxsDhjpjCMDSYsAHgAqxAB7AI9ACaUoABXQ1N6Y-CQHsAPm8AKMQAjACsKEwBKBTCLK1t7DxRSHAB+KBM2AHISQwy+KAoANzE4G0IFAEg4ZSgAkIA6bOxwsvLymj1BGmkg4IakxXKZJSgRqHbgTvpFIYUAelniJIBGKDh7BhsICFL0KAAiHgZGPYU1bWpFwxX8XX0kvyJGrAoM5TExAAFA5zqz1AzZOFFHMFk8AEyrda2LY7fZFEonM70C7gvBQW5eLAPKD0dCoCAvABi7wBMiBQA)

The usage of the function works as expected, but TypeScript throws some errors in the body:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends WithEmail ? T["email"] : void'

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T extends WithEmail ? T["email"] : void'.

I don't get why I have this error (`string` should be assignable to `string | void` in my opinion!), and therefore I don't know how to solve these falsy warnings. And I also wonder how `email1` and `email2` can be correctly typed despite these errors in the function body.

Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is just not supported: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929

Comment: FWIW you can accomplish the same thing in this example by using an [overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature), which won't produce an error on the return lines in your function.

Comment: I have the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71794000/generic-fetch-wrapper. Very unhappy